# Create a strip menu through vba

Tags: vba, menubar

Is it possible to create a form with a strip menu in it using vba (excel 2007).

If it is possible, is it possible to give me some insight about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is dated, but looks like it should be what you need (at least will get you started).

http://www.xcelfiles.com/API_Userform_MenuMaker.html